# Test In Progress is Empty in Jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I have Installed Test In Progress Plugin in Jenkins.And I am selecting the show test in progress option. I am Invoking Ant by specifying the build file name .The Job is Executed Successfully but I am unable to see the Test progress report(i.e it is empty).I have tried adding `testInProgress-testng-client-0.1.jar` to my `test classpath` but it shows no results.Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in [Test In Progress Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Test+In+Progress+Plugin), of an empty Test progress report in jenkins.

Solved it by adding ***testInProgress-testng-client*** in Maven POM dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
...
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.imaginea.jenkins.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>testInProgress-testng-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

And then, set the testinprogress listener (in my case for TestNG), under ***maven surefire/failsafe plugin*** configuration:

```
<configuration>
...
    <properties>
        <property>
            <name>listener</name>
            <value>org.imaginea.jenkins.plugins.testinprogress.testng.TestNGProgressRunListener</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
...
</configuration>
```